# Capitalise table of contents title with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, capitalization

Simple question, but I can't put the answer together through googleing. I want to capitalize the table of contents **TITLE** in my LaTeX document. Nothing else. I'm using the `tocloft` package and various links I've read through suggest renewing the `\cfttoctitlefont` command, but I haven't had much luck.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I'm putting any sorts of gibberish instead of the "TABLE OF CONTENTS" and there appears to be no effect on the toc title.

Comment: Please, show a minimal example; the code I gave should be in the preamble of the document (that is, before `\begin{document}`. Are you using `babel`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to capitalize the ToC title and not to use a different name, the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following example works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
\end{document}
```

Replace `TABLE OF CONTENTS` with what you want. If you're using `babel`, then a different way must be used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
\end{document}
```

Use `\captions<language>` for the language you're actually having as the main one.

The `titles` option to `tocloft` avoids that the package acts on the way titles for table of contents and "lists of" are managed.