# Package tocloft change font size

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, tocloft

So I have just started using `tocloft` in LaTeX for my report in order to generate a list of equations. The list works fine and it does what I need it to, but the only issue so far is that the heading 'List of Equations' is in much bigger font than the other headings for 'Contents' , ' List of Figures' etc... How can I change this?

Here is the code I have for the list.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listexamplename}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{example}
\par\noindent\text{Equation \theexample. #1}
\addcontentsline{exp}{example}
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theexample}#1}\par}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess that `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` may solve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

As already remarked in different contexts

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51900/4427
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53806/4427

the package `tocloft` uses its own method for typesetting the titles of the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables; so, if one's style for chapter headings is different, those three chapters' style will not match the others.

Use the `titles` option:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```